# Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in sources

Tags: apt, updates

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Obviously you added something to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is not sufficient to just paste the error messages, though that is useful too. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/930026/edit) your question and provide more details. What did you want to do? Which commands did you enter before you got the errors? Doing the same thing over and over won't give you the results you want.

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` and delete the 4th line if it's the same as the 3rd one. Easy way to "delete" is to comment out using a "#" as the first character on that line (arrow keys move the cursor). Ctrl+X to close, then Y to save.